# Japanese file name in zipped file is not showing correctly in ArchiveInputStream.getNextEntry().getName()

Tags: java, apache, zip, inputstream, apache-commons

My operating system is Windows 10 in Japanese language. Using Windows compressed file tool, I have created a zipped file that contains files with Japanese filenames. When I generate ArchiveInputStream from this file and get the filename of the files within using ArchiveInputStream.getNextEntry().getName(), the Japanese filenames are garbled. For example, 新しいテキスト ドキュメント.txt becomes �V�����e�L�X�g �h�L�������g.txt. How can I fix this problem?

```
S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(s3Setting.getBucketName(), s3FileKey));
InputStream inputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
try (ArchiveInputStream archiveStream = new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream(inputStream)) {
    ArchiveEntry entry = archiveStream.getNextEntry();
    while (entry != null) {
        String filename = StringUtils.removeEnd(FilenameUtils.normalize(entry.getName(), true), UNIX_SEPARATOR)
        ...
        entry = archiveStream.getNextEntry();
    }
}
```

Comment: `new String (ArchiveInputStream.getNextEntry().getName().getBytes (), "UTF8"))` ?

Comment: Which encoding did you use when you created the `ZipArchiveInputStream`? Please show your code, don't just describe it.

Comment: the zipped file is uploaded to Amazon S3 and downloaded with this line:`S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(s3Setting.getBucketName(), s3FileKey));`

Comment: You should use an encoding when you create the `ArchiveStreamFactory`. Please read the documentation.

Comment: How can I get the encoding of the filenames in the zipped file?